# Existence of a Hyperspace for any Vector Space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any Vector space $V$(as mentioned by @GEdgar: $V \neq\{0\}$). It contains a Maximal-Proper-Subspace.

I thought to use Zorn's Lemma to prove this statement. I considered $\Sigma:=$ Set of all proper subspaces of $V$. Now taking a chain $\{V_i:i \in I\}$ in $\Sigma$, I want to obtain an upper-bound of that chain by considering $\cup_{i \in I} V_i$ which is a subspace of $V$. But I cannot show $\cup_{i \in I} V_i$ is a proper-subspace of $V$.

I also thought of proving this in another way, let $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ be a basis for $V$. I take out only one element from basis say $x_{i_0}$. Now I want to show that the subspace generated by $\{x_i:i \in I\} \setminus \{x_{i_0}\}$ is maximal. But I cannot show that.

Note: I think in the second method Zorn's Lemma is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, once you use AC to get a Hamel basis, you do not need it again.  But we can do this with Zorn in almost the way you tried.

Note: your main assertion fails for $V = \{0\}$.  It has no proper subspace at all.

Now assume $V \ne \{0\}$.  Choose some $u \ne 0, u \in V$.  Then apply Zorn on Σ :=  Set of all subspaces of $V$ with $u  \notin V$.

Comment: Well I think in my first attempt the subspace $\cup_{i \in I}V_i$ may not be a proper subspace of V.  I am thinking of the space $V:= \prod_\limits{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$, with $V_i:=\mathbb{R^i}$. Then $\cup_{i \in I} V_i= \prod_\limits{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$. Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct.  In your first example, it can fail.

Comment: I noted a thing here. The maximal element obtained from $\Sigma$ is not yet a maximal proper subspace of $V$. It is a maximal subspace say $W$, which does not contain $u.$ Using maximality of $W$ in $\Sigma$ it can be shown that  $W$ contains all the elements of $V$ except scalar multiples of $u \implies W$ is a maximal proper subspace of $V$.